# How can I match at the beginning of any line, including the first, with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

According the [Perl documentation on regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions):

> By default, the "^" character is guaranteed to match only the beginning of the string ... Embedded newlines will not be matched by "^" ... You may, however, wish to treat a string as a multi-line buffer, such that the "^" will match **after any newline** within the string ... you can do this by using the /m modifier on the pattern match operator.

The "after any newline" part means that it will only match at the beginning of the 2nd and subsequent lines.  What if I want to match at the beginning of **any** line (1st, 2nd, etc.)?

**EDIT:** OK, it seems that the file has BOM information (3 chars) at the beginning and that's what's messing me up.  Any way to get ^ to match anyway?

**EDIT:** So in the end it works (as long as there's no BOM), but now it seems that the Perl documentation is wrong, since it says "after any newline"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `/^(?:\xEF\xBB\xBF)?/mg` regex to match at the beginning of the line anyway, if you want to preserve the BOM.

Answer (score 4):

The `^` *does* match the 1st line with the `/m` flag:

```
~:1932$ perl -e '$a="12\n23\n34";$a=~s/^/:/gm;print $a'
:12
:23
:34
```

To match with BOM you need to include it in the match.

```
~:1939$ perl -e '$a="ï»¿12\n23\n34";$a=~s/^(\d)/<\1>:/mg;print $a'
ï»¿12
<2>:3
<3>:4
~:1940$ perl -e '$a="ï»¿12\n23\n34";$a=~s/^(?:ï»¿)?(\d)/<\1>:/mg;print $a'
<1>:2
<2>:3
<3>:4
```

Comment: It's not working when I'm reading from a file.  Could there be something hidden in my file?

Comment: @Joel: I think so. BOM maybe?

Comment: It's a Visual Studio file.  I just reduced it to 1 character, and "dir" says the size is 4, so something is going on! Also, when I do "type", I see 3 strange characters at the beginning of the file

Comment: @Joel: They are probably `ï»¿` (EF BB BF). Try to save the file as UTF-8 **without** byte order mark.

Comment: @KennyTM What if I can't change the files (there are many, and they need to be read back into Visual Studio, so I don't want to mess with that)?

Comment: There's a `File::BOM` on CPAN that will detect and ignore the BOM for you, which should make life easier. Also, the docs aren't wrong; the prose is just a little twisty. There's an implicit "also" in there :)

Comment: @hobbs, thanks... that sounds better than using the regeex, I'll check it out

Comment: I guess somebody set me up the BOM

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, there's assumed to be a newline before the beginning of the string.  Consequently, /^a/ will find a letter 'a' at the beginning of a string.

Answer (score -1):

*Put a empty line at the beginning of the file*, this cool things down, and avoid to make `regex` hard to read.

Yes, the BOM.  It might appear at the beginning of the file, so put an empty at the beginning of the file.  The *BOM* will not be `\s`, or something can be seen by bare eye.  It kills my hours when a BOM make my `regex` fail.